# The contents from my .xml file sometimes appears on my webpage when I load it, but when I refresh, it disappears. (javascript, jquery, ajax, xml)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

In this project, I am creating a `contact.js` file for the `contact.html` file that will pull the data from the `listings.html` file and append its entire contents to the `aboutUs` `div` in the `contact.html` page. I wrote a function to make the contents from the `listings.html` file appear in the `contact.html` file.

In addition, in the `contact.js` file, I wrote a function that will append all the contents of my `realtors.xml` file right below the contents of the `listings.html` file in the `aboutUs` `div` in the `contact.html` page. My function works, but sometimes when I load the `contact.html` webpage, it displays the contents of the `realtors.xml` file, but other times it does not appear. On the other hand, the contents of the `listings.html` file always appears on my webpage when I load it. Sometimes I have to refresh my webpage twice or three times to get the contents of the `realtors.xml` file to appear, and other times, the contents of the `realtors.xml` file still appear after refreshing the webpage 5 times in a row. I want the contents of the `realtors.xml` file to always appear on my webpage every single time I load the webpage, but it occurs sometimes.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am using a `contact.html` file, a `contact.js` file, a `realtors.xml` file and a `listings.html` file (and a jquery file (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js)).

My `contact.html` file is this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>Real Estate Sold</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="listing.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="contact.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
                <div>
                    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Regional Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Current Listings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sold</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
         <div id="aboutUs"></div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

My `contact.js` file is this:

```
 $("document").ready(function() {
        getData();
        getXMLData();
      });

      function getData() {
        $("#aboutUs").load("listings.html");
      }

  function getXMLData() {
        $.get("realtors.xml", function(result) {
            var phone = result.getElementsByTagName("phone")[0];
            var name = result.getElementsByTagName("name")[0];
            var realtor = name.firstChild.nodeValue + " : " + phone.firstChild.nodeValue;
            var phone1 = result.getElementsByTagName("phone")[1];
            var name1 = result.getElementsByTagName("name")[1];
            var para = document.createElement("P");                     
            var t = document.createTextNode(realtor1);      
            var realtor1 = name1.firstChild.nodeValue + " : " + phone1.firstChild.nodeValue;
            $("#aboutUs").append(realtor);
            $("#aboutUs").append(para).append(realtor1);
        });
      }
```

My `listings.html` file is this:

```
<h2>About Us</h2>
<p> Wright Realty is a family owned real estate brokerage specializing in custom homes since 1852.  
    We appreciate that our customers demand quality that endures for generations, so we only
    list with homeowners who have maticulously maintained their unique and timeless homes.
</p>
<h3>Our Realtors:</h3>
<ul></ul>
```

My `realtors.xml` file is this:

```
<data>
    <name>Frank Lloyd</name>
    <phone>555-123-4567</phone>
    <name>Lloyd Wright</name>
    <phone>555-123-8910</phone>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the (asynchronous) handling of `realtors.xml` can happen before the loading of `listings.html`, and can get overwritten by it.

You have to either:

- Call `getXMLData()` after the loading of `listings.html` is finished by providing it as a `complete`-callback (see http://api.jquery.com/load/), or
- Create two different divs to place the content in so that it does not matter what is loaded first.

First method would look like this:

```
  $("document").ready(function() {
    getData();
  });

  function getData() {
    $("#aboutUs").load("listings.html", getXMLData);
  }
```

Comment: I see what you mean. But is there a way to change only the contact.js file?

Comment: Yes, see above. Call getXMLData() after the loading of listings.html is finished by providing it as a complete-callback (see http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: How would I add a complete-callback? And what goes into the callback? I read the website, but its still confusing.

Comment: Something like `$("#aboutUs").load("listings.html", getXMLData);`. There is an example at the bottom of the API docs page.

Comment: No, in `getData`. Append it to the existing line, and remove the original call to `getXMLData` from `document.ready`.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesnt work. This is your version: 
 'code'
 $("document").ready(function() {
  getData();
      });
      
      function getData() {   
        $("#aboutUs").load("listings.html", getXMLData()); 
      } 'code'

Comment: Remove the parentheses after `getXMLData`.